# Explication de la prononciation de « atome »

Tags: prononciation, voyelles

Pourquoi le  « o » de « atome » se prononce-t-il comme dans  « icône » alors que celui-ci ne porte pas d'accent circonflexe ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D'après le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/atome):

> Forme phon. : [ato:m]. Le phonème o est fermé et long ,,dans la plupart des mots où il est suivi d'un seul m (...), qu'on l'écrive ou non avec un accent circonflexe`` (Grammont Prononc. 1958, p. 18).

Cela dit, la prononciation [atɔm] est courante, et même l'usage dans le sud de la France.

Comment: Dans le sud de la France, ne pas confondre l'atome avec la tome, qui est plus goutûe.

Comment: @Nathan La to**m**me crochue est plus go**û**tue ! ;-)

Comment: Méchant! Merci de la correction, je confonds toujours pour "goûtu". Bizarre alors que je ne me pose pas la question pour "goût"...

Answer (score 2):

D'après le [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/atome) :

> PRONONC. ET ORTH. − 1. Forme phon. : [ato:m]. Le phonème o est fermé et long ,,dans la plupart des mots où il est suivi d'un seul m (...), qu'on l'écrive ou non avec un accent circonflexe`(Grammont Prononc. 1958, p. 18). Buben 1935, p. 41, indique que ces mots ,,prennent souvent un o bref, sous l'influence des mots en -omme`. Fouché Prononc. 1959, p. 79, indique que le [o] s'ouvre lorsqu'il devient inaccentué dans les dérivés : atomique, atomisme, etc. Enq. : /atom, D/. 2. Forme graph. − Fér. Crit. t. 1 1787 écrit atôme.